# Rename Package name using gradle in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, package

I have an application with package name as *com.test.project1* and I have to use the same code for building another application with package name *com.test.project2*. My requirement is to rename the package name of the application using gradle, so that I just have to change the package name in the gradle file to build another application using the same code.

I have added applicationId in the gradle file and its working but the directory name is not changing. Since the directory name is not changing I am not getting the *GCM registration Id*.I don't want to refactor the name manually. Is it possible to change the directory name of an Android application using Gradle?

Answer (score 0):

sure , just place applicationId different. It won't change the directory names, but you it will be different and you can put both in google shop

Comment: But still the OP has to refactor

Comment: Since directory name is not changing, I am not getting the GCM registration Id